# How to get a Video file path in Python

Tags: python

I have a video file of .avi format.I need to know the actual location of the video file in my system.
I tried a code,

```
import os 

name='DLINK-IP-CAM-2018-10-16-10-06-31.avi' 

var=os.path.abspath(name) 

print(var)
```

i get an output as follows,

```
cmdevlin12@cmdevlin12:~/Desktop$ python search.py
/home/cmdevlin12/Desktop/DLINK-IP-CAM-2018-10-16-10-06-31.avi
```

but this is actually the location of the python file "search.py" not the location of video file.

Can anyone please help me to solve the issue?

Comment: Where is this file actually located?

Comment: I'm confused. Are you trying to search your whole filesystem for a video file given the name?

Answer (score 0):

If, as it appears, you wish to search your whole filesystem (or at least a drive) for your file, then this might do the trick:

```
import os

def search(drive,name):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(drive):
        if name in files:
            return (os.path.join(dirpath, name))
```

Call the function with the root of a drive as the first parameter, and your filename as the second, and it will find it for you or return None. BUT be prepared for a potentially long wait!